# opening android sqlite database files on command line on android studio 3.0.2

Tags: android, sqlite

I have built a basic database program and wish to see the data that has been saved in the emulator. (locating the databases file within the apps file explorer and saving file to  desktop) However, when I try and bring up the database through the command line (.tables) nothing comes up at all.

I have searched online and tried an API less than 23 which didn't work.

I am running Android 3.0.2 and the emulator is a Nexus x5 API p. I have downloaded SQLite3 which is working because I can build and view database files outside of android studio.

Does anyone know why this is happening? [image]

Comment: For see the database files,Alternatively you can use the DB Browser for SQ Lite software.

Comment: Are you sure that you are in the right directory? It looks like you are in `Users/Sam/Desktop` and that's not where your database is.

Comment: I saved a copy to the desktop

Comment: I downloaded the DB browser which worked for other sqlite directories but did not show any info for the shelter database. I will try and run a different emulator which will hopefully solve this problem

Comment: Oh ok, can you test whether your database is not empty, for example `SELECT * FROM pets`.

Comment: I have run it on a different emulator running an API 22 but this did not work either. I ran SELECT * FROM pets and my database is empty. Either there is a bug in my version of the program or a bug in my code

Comment: Changed the saved location of shelter.db file from Desktop to Documents and now it is opening and working. My project file was saved within a folder on the desktop so I guess that this was the problem?